Older movie about woman kept against her will in a nice house
I can't remember the exact plot but I partially watched this movie a few years ago and forgot the name. Might have been on Sony Channel (Dish network).
Basically, from what I remember, it was color (pretty grainy on a hd tv) seemed like it's from the 60-70s, most likely American or Canadian, English language.
It was about a guy who kept a woman (student possibly?) in his house which was very nice (villa-like from what I remember) and basically kept her imprisoned.
Edit: The antagonist had a very psycho quality to him (dark hair I believe) and at a point in the movie the woman tried playing along with what she thought he wanted hoping he would set her free. Can't remember too much details about the woman though. At some point, I think there was someone making an inquiry to the home, possibly a police officer or detective.
The antagonist was in love with the woman, tried to play "house" with her.
The genre is horror/thriller/psychological thriller.
A google search suggested it might be Something Wild (1961) but it's definitely not that. No other results for me describing this criteria.
Edit 2:
Not Ruthless People. The movie was pretty dark and much older.

@Paulie_D I found it. Should I delete thread or leave it?

@AndrewB don't answer in question itself, better is you can self answer your own question.

Found it. The answer is The Collector (1965)

A man kidnaps a woman and holds her hostage just for the pleasure of having her there.


Actually, it's "The Collector".

Aside from the typo, why the downvote on the answer to the question?

@TimS., theres a warning on this answer saying it is too minimal and might be removed. Just a guess, but that would probably be why.

It's because you might want to elaborate in which way this fits to the details from the question in order to flesh out this answer a litle more.
